# Adding TerrainLayer with deckgl in R from local raster DEM

Tags: r, deck.gl

I am trying to use the `deckgl` library in R to create a TerrainLayer based on a downloaded bathymetry raster layer from the `marmap` package (however, the process would apply to any DEM raster layer).

See below for reproducible example, I don't understand why deckgl is not rendering the terrain layer, but I suspect it's something with how the png image is produced?

```
library(marmap)
library(deckgl)
library(raster)

# noaa bathy
b <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = -74.2, lon2 =  -73.3, lat1=40.3,
                   lat2 = 40.7, resolution = 0.1)

# convert to raster and save as png?
r <- as.raster(b)
png(file = "output/bathy_grey.png")
raster::plot(r, maxpixels=ncell(r), col=grey.colors(255), 
             axes=FALSE, box=FALSE, legend=FALSE)
dev.off()

elevation_data <- normalizePath( "output/bathy_grey.png")
bounds =  c(r@extent@xmin, r@extent@ymin, r@extent@xmax, r@extent@ymax)

elevation <-  sprintf("data:image/png;base64,%s", base64enc::base64encode(elevation_data))

elev_map = list(
  rScaler = 1,
  gScaler = 0,
  bScaler = 0,
  offset = 0  
)

props = list(
  strategy = "no-overlap",
  elevationDecoder = elev_map,
  elevationData = elevation,
  bounds = bounds 
)

deckgl(
  latitude = 40.5,
  longitude = -74,
  zoom = 10,
  pitch = 45,
  height = "600px") |> 
  add_basemap() |> 
  add_layer("TerrainLayer",
            id = "terrain",
            properties = props)
```

I have successfully used the same procedure to download a local copy of the example png image used in deckgl docs, by downloading this file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visgl/deck.gl-data/master/website/terrain.png locally and loading it as `elevation_data` in the above, so I suspect that there is "something different" about these 2 pngs that TerrainLayer isn't liking, but I'm not sure what.